# check the existing table to insert a column, the value is present there or not?

Tags: java, sql-server

I have to insert the values in the table named "First", but before inserting the value i have to check whether the row exists there or not with a following Registered "name". If the row value is present there, then i have to remove that row and insert the values present in that row to different table named "second". Then, i have to insert the my present value to the "first" table.

I am Using SQL server 2005

Comment: I can do it with java code, which would be lengthy. So, i m looking for a query which would be helpful

Comment: What database are you using? Edit your question to put the name of it in, people will be able to help then.

Comment: What database are you using? In Oracle for example exists a system table (ALL_TABLES) which contains the description of all relational tables accessible to the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to me as you are trying to create history table. It is usually done in trigger because it covers all possible scenarios.

Here is a stored procedure you might call from java to insert or update First:

```
create proc ReplaceName (@Name varchar(100), @Value1 varchar(100), @Value2 varchar(100))
as
   set nocount on
-- try to update Name with new values
   update [First]
      set Value1 = @Value1,
          Value2 = @Value2
    where Name = @Name
-- If it does not exist
   if @@rowcount = 0
   begin
-- Insert new row
      insert into [First] (Name, Value1, Value2)
           values (@Name, @Value1, @Value2)
   end
```

And this is a trigger that saves old copies into second:

```
create trigger HistoryFirst on [First]
after insert, update
as
   set nocount on

   insert into [Second] (Name, Value1, Value2)
        select Name, Value1, Value2
          from Deleted
```